# Парсинг JSON в Java Android

Tags: json, java, android, синтаксический-анализ

Всем привет!

Помогите, пожалуйста, розпарсить такую запись:

```
{"stts":{"s":1,"td":{"cid":"72345","zn":"njiw"},"st":true}}
```

Нужно получить доступ ко всем элементам. Как это можно сделать?

Уже два дня мучаюсь с JSONObject и getJSONArray:

```
//response - строка ответа сервера
private JSONObject json;
private JSONArray values;

json = new JSONObject(response); //Тут все ок

values = json.getJSONArray("stts");//А тут ловлю краш
```

Лог:

```
 11-07 17:19:15.491: W/System.err(271): org.json.JSONException: Value {"s":1,"td":{"cid":"72345","zn":"njiw"},"st":true} at s of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: Ну так расскажите, как мучаетесь в деталях. :-)

Comment: @Чад ок)Обновил)

Comment: @Чад я пользуюсь json_encode (PHP) и он так возвращает, добавления вроде json_encode(array(json => $json)) ни к чему не привело.Возвращает так как я написал выше. Задача состоит в том что бы получить все значения. А как сделать это с теми элементами что внутри stts я понятия не имею.

Comment: Ещё раз - у вас внутри не массив, а хэш. Берёте как JSONObject от jsonObject'a.

Comment: @Чад можно увидеть как это выглядит. Просто даже представить трудно.

Comment: @Чад прошу прощение.Но есть реальное задание, которое нужно сделать в строки, и изучение ведется "на лету", только тогда запутываюсь, задаю вопросы. А так основы прочитал. Общей документации на русском не нашел, а с английским беда. Переведите, пожалуйста, в ответ и я приму как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так у вас `stts` это не массив, а JSONObject тоже, берите его:

`json.getJSONObject("stts");`

массив это когда `[]` т.е. `{"stts":[{"s":1},{"td":...}]}`